Flet mobile application client side storage
I am currently developing a flet mobile app where the user enters data and the app stores it persistently and makes it availabe to view.
Now I am trying to figure out how to store local data on the client side. I found the client storage (https://flet.dev/docs/cookbook/client-storage) API, but it seems not safe to use at all, because all Flet applications are using the same storage.
Especially this part of the documentation makes it in my oppinion very risky to use:

caution
clear() is a dangerous function that removes all preferences of all Flet apps ever run by the same user and serves as a heads-up that permanent application data shouldn't be stored in the client storage.

Is there a good API or package that I can use for my client side stroage? I just want to save a single JSON file in the local os storage, but I want to make sure that it works well on ios, android and windows.
